# Random error "ethereum is not defined" in Vue development boilerplate

Tags: vue.js, web3js, metamask

I am trying to implement web3 in a very basic Vue3 component using Vue basic boilerplate created with vue-cli but I have some weird errors.

First things first, here is the code of my component:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/images/logo.png">
  <pre v-if="account">{{ account }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      account: undefined
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    if (typeof ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
      this.account = accounts[0]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The first issue I run into, is that when I launch the environment with `npm run serve` and when I change some code in my component, I have the following error in my test window as well as in my terminal:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.vue Module Error (from
> ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> /home/arnaud/Code/_BLOCKCHAIN/crypto-app/src/App.vue   16:30  error
> 'ethereum' is not defined  no-undef
>
> 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

And the second weird behavior, is that I sometimes also have this error in my terminal when starting the environment but sometimes not. When I don't have the error at start, and if I don't change anything in the code, my application seems to run without error.

Comment: const { ethereum } = window; plus metamask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install metamask extension first and then check for ethereum instance like

```
const {ethereum} =window;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an eslint error, because you are trying to use ethereum variable in a a scope where it is not declared in. If ethereum is already declared in the global scope. You can disable the eslint for this line.

```
async mounted() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    if (typeof ethereum !== 'undefined') {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
      this.account = accounts[0]
    }
```

otherwise you would have to define/import ethereum in the component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually `ethereum` is an object which is injected in webpages by Metamask browser extension. I think it must mess with eslint for some reason :/

Comment: Indeed, Edited my answer this should work now. Just add       // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef